# How can I handle array intersection in find({})?

Tags: mongodb

there is an array ,for example:

```
var arr = ["1","1.1","1.3","2","2.1","2.2","2.3"]
```

and a Collection A ,just like this

```
[
  {_id:"1",children:["1.1","1.4"]},
  {_id:"2",children:["2.1","2.2"]},
  {_id:"3",children:["3.1","3.2"]}
]
```

by

```
find({....})
```

I want to get the result

```
[
  {_id:"1",children:["1.1"]},
  {_id:"2",children:["2.1","2.2"]},
]
```

the result children's array is the intersection that  `arr` and collection `A`'s `children`

how can i set the query operator?

Answer (score 4):

Also this is not the exact answer you are looking for, but you can go pretty close with [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array) operator:

```
db.i.find({
  children : { $in : arr}
})
```

Keep in mind that this will not produce the abovementioned result (it will output all the values in the array and not `{_id:"1",children:["1.1"]},`).

But you can to what I suggested and after this in your application iterate through all results and to output only intersection of children with your array.

Comment: so basically, here's something that gives a different result than what you want? :)

Comment: @AsyaKamsky no, I did not know how to achieve everything that OP wants in mongo, so I gave him a solution that makes a mongoquery and then needs to do some application logic and would achieve the result he wants. But I am glad you gave a complete solution and happy to give you +1

Comment: I didn't give him what he wanted either (hence the :) ) but of course a simple "find" cannot do what he is asking ... so we're both in the same boat in that regard.

Comment: According to this [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the--in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array) from the documentation, this is now the right way of doing the query he wants. I'm adding this comment just for future references.

Answer (score 4):

You can't achieve the result you want via a simple query (find) but you can do it using the aggregation framework.  Here's how:

```
var arr = ["1","1.1","1.3","2","2.1","2.2","2.3"]

db.A.aggregate([ { "$unwind" : "$children" }, 
                 { "$match"  : { "children" : { "$in" : arr } } },
                 { "$group"  : { "_id" : "$_id", "children" : { "$push" : "$children" } } }
               ]
);
```

Result from your sample data:

```
{ "_id" : "2", "children" : [  "2.1",  "2.2" ] }
{ "_id" : "1", "children" : [  "1.1" ] }
```